# Javascript file conflicting with parents style on wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

So i've added a lightbox (using lightbox2) to my site(https://linton59.co.uk/) Since adding the following file

```
 wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox2',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.0', true );
```

My website now has none of the images on the banners i've previously added. Furthermore it seems some of the previous style.css is overwritten.

The following is my functions.php file

```
    <?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_light', 30 );
function theme_light() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'simpleshift_public' );


wp_enqueue_style( 'lightbox', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/lightbox.css', array(), '4.3.0' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'lightbox2',  get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/lightbox-plus-jquery.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.0', true );


}


// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts', 20 );
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_script( 'simpleshift_public' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() .'/js/public.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0', true);
}



if ( !function_exists( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css' ) ):
    function chld_thm_cfg_parent_css() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'chld_thm_cfg_parent', trailingslashit( get_template_directory_uri() ) . 'style.css', array( 'bootstrap','font-awesome' ) );
    }
endif;
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'chld_thm_cfg_parent_css', 10 );
```

Comment: Have you tried flipping the order? Load the lightbox first and then your site's styles.

Comment: Yea just tried it there and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I just checked your website: You have JavaScript errors: `jQuery(...).niceScroll is not a function`, so it looks like you are missing a jQuery plugin.

Comment: updated my question with a new error.

Comment: Have you published these changes on your website? I don't see any JS errors anymore.

Comment: Updated my question again. Sorry i'm trying to fix things as well and seem to unearth or sweep errors under the rug as i go. So yea i'm seeing that nice scroll error at the moment.

Comment: Okay to avoid extending this out to a different question. I have fixed the error was having but of course that seems to make my lightbox not work anymore as the image popups and you have to close that to get the lightbox to work..

Comment: Thankyou for the help and suggestions though.